# grunt-assemble with handlebars: how to get an array into a partial?

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, partial

i want to generate with grunt-assemble static sites, everything works fine but i have a problem to get an array into a partial

this is my partial(image-slider.hbs) which should recive the array

```
<div class="swiper-container {{className}}">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {{#each images}}
            <img  class="swiper-slide" src="{{ ../path }}/{{image}}" alt="">
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and from this partial(office-slider.hbs) i want to send the data

```
... 
<h1>images from the office</h1>
{{> image-slider 
    className='office-slider' 
    path='..img' 
    images=[
        "image": "t_1.jpg",
        "image": "t_2.jpg",
        "image": "t_3.jpg",
        "image": "t_1.jpg",
        "image": "t_2.jpg",
        "image": "t_3.jpg",
    ]
}}
...
```

office-slider.hbs is included office.hbs

```
...
{{>office-slider}}
...
```

"className" and "path" works fine, but if i try to put an array as a data i get only an error

Warning: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.

what im doing wrong?

gregor

Comment: don't put data in templates, they are supposed to free you from that burden...

Comment: what should i else do? this works realy easy another example is a button where i can simply put the labeltext into the partial. {{ >button label="myLabel"}} button.hbs: <button>{{label}}</button>

Comment: i just noticed that the images array is mal-formed. i still don't recommend putting large amounts of data as params, but the HB parser might not explode anymore if you fix the array...

Comment: if i write it this way i get also the same error images=[
  "t_praxis1.jpg",
  "t_praxis2.jpg",
  "t_praxis3.jpg",
  "t_praxis1.jpg",
  "t_praxis2.jpg",
  "t_praxis3.jpg",
 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On advice from @dandavis i seperated my data out of the template and this is how it works

my gruntfile

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        partials: ['partials/**/*.hbs'],
        layoutdir: 'layouts',
        layout: ['default.hbs'],
        flatten: true,
        data: ['pages/**/*.json'],  <--load all jsons (contains the data)
        helpers: ['js/helper-*.js']
    },
    site: {
        src: ['pages/**/*.hbs'],
        dest: 'build/pages/'
    }
}
```

create home.json (in my case it's located in the directory "pages/home/" next to home.hbs)

```
{
    "title": "pagetitle",
    "gallery1": ["item1.jpg", "item2.jpg","item3.jpg"] 
}
```

inside my home.hbs i load the partial with the data from home.json

```
{{home.title}}
{{>image_bar data=home.gallery1}}
```

and now i have full access to the data in my partial (image_bar.hbs)

```
<ul>
    {{#each data}} 
        <li><img  src="../img/{{this}}"></li > 
    {{/each}} 
</ul>
```